# Getting the error " Error running 'app' Unknown Error Please file a bug against Android Studio"

Tags: android, android-studio

I have Android Studio Hedgehog and I am trying to run my application but everytime that I do it I get the error mentioned in the title.

Is this a common issue? If I try to build my application it builds fine.
Is there any file that I can see logs about the error?

Comment: Check out your Logcat and share complete errro why you get this error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on macOs Sonoma 14.2.1 on a MacBook Pro 2021 with M1 Pro Chip.

In my case deleting the "Lib/Android/sdk" folder solved it.

I think the problem come from the Apple migration tool: I migrated from my old Intel MacBookPro and it copied the sdk's during the migration.

I hope this answer will help you.